# Mongodb - show subArray in query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am selecting by a key and with it I need to show on each line the values that are inside the statistics array:

```
[
    {"$match": { "key": {"$eq" : "5edfa70cc75f1"} } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": "$name",
            "date" :  "$statistics.date",
            "value" :  "$statistics.value",
            "_id" : false
        },
    },
    
]
```

When executing this code the return is only one line with the values inside an array:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjfOI.png)

I need this data to be one per line per day.

Comment: can u post some sample data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting questions, please add relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage in between `$match` and `$project`. `$unwind` will create a document for each element in an array. Your complete aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
[
    {"$match": { "key": {"$eq" : "5edfa70cc75f1"} } },
    {"$unwind": "$statistics" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": "$name",
            "date" :  "$statistics.date",
            "value" :  "$statistics.value",
            "_id" : false
        },
    },
    
]
```